# laravel 5.2 setting default locale in app.php does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want to set the default locale to zh-tw from en, i changed the locale='en' to locale='zh-tw' in \config\app.php,

```
'locale' => 'zh-tw',
```

but the view is keep using 'resources\lang\en',

i've also tried but all not useful:
added `APP_LOCALE in .env=zh-tw` 
run `php artisan cache:clear`

Why \config\app.php locale setting has no effect and meanless in laravel?

Except to run setlocale('zh-tw') in every controller or create a middleware to set language, is there any other simplest method to change the default locale in few seconds?

Comment: Hope you have already created 'resources\lang\zh-tw'

Comment: Do oyu need to do a clear cache "php artisan clear:cache" or "cache:clear" i can never remember

Answer (score 3):

To set the locale and make it work properly you need to do below configurations:

1) First make your locale folder inside `\resources\lang\YOUR_LOCALE_NAME`.

2) Then add file `messages.php` or as per your need. which has following structure:

```
<?php

return array(
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
);
```

3) Then go to `\config\app.php` and set the locale as your `LOCALE_FOLDER_NAME`.

4) Remember to set `fallback_locale` in `app.php` which will be used in case `YOUR_LOCALE_NAME` is not found.

Comment: already done before ask, this not work for me so strange. I have deleted the en folder entirely, it echo 'vendor/profile.my_profile' to me, the view code is {{ Lang::get("vendor/profile.my_profile") }}

Comment: i use dd(App::getLocale()); in route.php, it shows 'en'

Comment: i have found \bootstrap\cache\config.php is caching the config, any idea to  refresh this file?

Comment: `php artisan clear-compiled` and then `php artisan composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @ali you mean `composer dump-autoload` not `php artisan ..`

Answer (score 3):

To modify the **`hideDefaultLocaleInURL`** parameter in the **`config/laravellocalization.php`** file.

**From:**

> 'hideDefaultLocaleInURL' => false

**To:**

> 'hideDefaultLocaleInURL' => true

Answer (score 0):

just go to `config/app.php` and look for `locale` key and change it whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to do below instructions:

1. First make your locale folder inside \resources\lang\LOCALE_NAME.
2. Then you have to add files which has following structure:

   ```
   <?php return [    
    'reset' => 'Your password has been reset!',
    'sent' => 'We have emailed your password reset link!',
    'throttled' => 'Please wait before retrying.',
    'token' => 'This password reset token is invalid.',
    'user' => "We can't find a user with that email address.",];
   ```
3. Then you have to go to \config\app.php and set locale as your LOCALE_FOLDER_NAME.

   **'locale' => 'LOCALE_NAME',**
4. After this you have to clear your config cache. Go to your terminal and paste this code to clear it.

   **php artisan config:cache**

*Note:
Some times you could get an error like this:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [view.engine.resolver] does not exist.
```

Just run the following code in the root of your application in your system terminal.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

1. run `php artisan config:cache` command in your root directory of the laravel project
2. check if it works fine
3. go to **/bootstrap/cache** address to find **config.php** and delete it if exists